# Sum, Average of elements and Count the occurence of elements in Lists in Prolog

Tags: count, sum, prolog, average

how can I write three predicates in Prolog that do the following things:

1) Define the `sum (X, N)` predicate, which is true when N is the sum of integers from the list X.

2) Define the `avg (X, N)` predicate that calculates the arithmetic average of all elements of the list X, where N is the number of elements.

3) Define the predicate called `count(X, Y, N)`, which is true if the list Y contains N element instances
X.

Could you give me the examples of them and explain to me why they work the way they do? I know there are dozens of sum and avg predicates here on Stack Overflow, but I can't really understand why they work.

Answer (score 0):

> Define the `sum(X, N)` predicate, which is true when `N` is the sum of integers from the list `X`.

You want to calculate the sum of the elements of a list. What would be the simplest instance of the problem? When the list is empty, the sum of its element is `0`. How can we break down larger lists to get to the simple case? We can remove the first element of the list, calculate the sum of the remaining list, and then add the first element to the result.

This approach can be implemented with the following code:

```
% Simple case: Sum of the empty list
sum([], 0).

% Recursive case: Split list into first element X and remaining list XS
sum([X|XS], N) :- sum(XS, M), N is M + X.
```

Usage:

```
?- sum([1,2,3],6).
true.
?- sum([1,2,3],X).
X = 6.
```

The `is` operator does arithmetic evaluation of its right-hand side ([reference](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2)), as opposed to treating `M + X` as a literal term. If you would use `=` instead of `is`, `M + X` would be treated as a literal term. You would then get the following output:

```
?- sum([1,2,3],6).
false.
?- sum([1,2,3],0+3+2+1).
true.
```

So for Prolog `6` and `0+3+2+1` are different terms, until you force arithmetic evaluation as done by `is`.

> 2) Define the avg (X, N) predicate that calculates the arithmetic average of all elements of the list X, where N is the number of elements.

This is not possible. If `X` is the list and `N` the number of elements, then the predicate has no way of outputting the average (unless you count printing the average as a side-effect, I don't think you want). To fix this, add another parameter `A` that represents the average: `avg(X, N, A)`.

We can calculate the average by taking the sum of the list and dividing it by the length of the list:

```
avg(X, N, A) :- sum(X, S), length(X, N), A is S / N.
```

Usage:

```
?- avg([1,2,3],3,2).
true.
?- avg([1,2,3,4],N,X).
N = 4,
X = 2.5.
```

> 3) Define the predicate called count(X, Y, N), which is true if the list Y contains N element instances X.

I understand you want `N` to be the number of times that the number `X` occurs in the list `Y`. We can again break this down into a simple case and then try to break down the general case into smaller steps until we get to the simple case.
For an empty list, we know that `X` occurs zero times in that list. For a non-empty list, we can remove the first element and check of how often `X` occurs in the remaining list. If the first element if equal to `X`, then the total number of occurrences of `X` is one plus the number of occurrences in the remaining list. If the first element is not equal to `X`, then the total number of occurrences of `X` is equal to the number of occurrences in the remaining list.

This approach can be implemented with the following code:

```
% Simple case: The list is empty.
count(_, [], 0).

% Recursive case: First element is equal to X
count(X, [X|YS], N) :- count(X, YS, M), N is M + 1, !.

% Recursive case: First element is unequal to X
count(X, [Y|YS], N) :- X \= Y, count(X, YS, N).
```

We use `_` for variables we do not care about. We could also write `X` instead of `_`, but Prolog would then give us a warning about an unused variable.

Usage:

```
?- count(1, [1,1,2,3], N).
N = 2.
?- count(2, [1,1,2,3], N).
N = 1.
```